# Simple OpenGL Clarification

Tags: opengl

Does version OpenGL 3+ only uses "GL_TRIANGLES" ?

That's what I read, but in the documentation for OpenGL 3.3, http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/, "glDrawArrays()" takes the following parameters:

```
GL_POINTS,
GL_LINE_STRIP,
GL_LINE_LOOP,
GL_LINES,
GL_LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY,
GL_LINES_ADJACENCY,
GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
GL_TRIANGLE_FAN,
GL_TRIANGLES,
GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP_ADJACENCY,
GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENCY
```

Comment: Could you clarify that? `glDrawArrays` can receive all of the above, as you have read in the manual. So what is it that you want to know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does version OpenGL 3+ only uses "GL_TRIANGLES"

You mean "instead of also offering GL_QUADS and GL_POLYGON"?

Yes indeed. Quads and Polygons have been removed altogether. Most polygons needed to be tesselated into triangles anyway, since OpenGL can deal with convex polygons only (convex also imples planar!). Similar holds for quads.

Lines and points remain to be supported of course.

Answer (score 2):

> Does version OpenGL 3+ only uses "GL_TRIANGLES" ?? That's what I read

Where? Please provide a link.

There is a difference between "GL_TRIANGLES" and "triangles".

GL_TRIANGLES is a *specific* primitive type. It has [a specific interpretation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitives). It's base primitive type is "triangles" (as in, it generates triangles), but there's more to it than that.

"triangles" are exactly that: assemblages of 3 vertices that represent a planar area. GL_TRIANGLES, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, and GL_TRIANGLE_FAN *produce* triangles.

OpenGL 3.1+ core does not allow the use of the specific primitive types GL_QUADS, GL_QUAD_STRIP (ie: all "quad" types), and GL_POLYGON. Everything else is fair game.

Comment: what do you mean by "core"? is there a difference between   OpenGL 3+ and OpenGL 3+ core?

Comment: I mean [core OpenGL.](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts)

Answer (score 1):

According to section 2.6.1 of the specification commands like glDrawArrays() accept the primitives you posted. So, no, OpenGL 3.3 doesn't accept just GL_TRIANGLES.

What you read was probably meant to explain that OpenGL doesn't support primitives like GL_QUADS and GL_POLYGON anymore.

Quad and polygon primitives have been removed according to appendix E.2.2 of the specification (since version 3.1, prior versions still support them, although they're deprecated from version 3.0).

You can find the specification [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/).

Comment: "although they're deprecated from version 3.1" Not true. They are _deprecated_ in 3.0 (deprecated means "still exists but subject to removal later). They are _removed_ in 3.1.

Comment: Nicol Bolas, you're correct, the spec is a bit confusing when it comes to deprecation.

Comment: No, the spec is quite clear when it comes to this stuff. Just look at the 3.1 specification, where it states what deprecation means. In Appendix G.2, it clearly states what was _removed_ in version 3.1.

Comment: That's exactly what I found confusing, first listing the features deprecated in 3.0 in E.1 and then saying they're removed from 3.1 in G2. I assumed that because they reiterated parts of 3.0, those parts also applied to 3.1. I guess I need to take things very literally and assume nothing when it comes to specs like this.